# Can I set NS values on the webserver instead of on the nameserver?

Tags: dns, webserver, domain-registrar, nameserver

I can only ask the domain registrar (Cyber) by email or by phone to change the domain's NS values, I don't have direct access to the DNS settings.

I asked Cyber's support to change the NS values of the domain (drszalayeva.hu) to `ns1.nethely.hu` and `ns2.nethely.hu`, but they said:

> Please set the domain name on the new server. 
> We cannot change the name servers until the domain name is set on the new server.

So, first I've set the NS values on the old webhosting provider from where I'd like to move the site (`ns8.nameservers.co.uk` & `ns2238.nameservers.co.uk`) from. And now the site ([drszalayeva.hu](https://drszalayeva.hu/)) is up and running properly, and at the new webhosting provider there aren't any errors, but when I run a technical verification, I get the following:

```
M-GREET     -I- [drszalayeva.hu] Domi version 20220219 at 2023-02-13.21:19
M-STAR  -I- [drszalayeva.hu] NS parameter not given, getting it from DNS
M-PNAM  -I- [drszalayeva.hu] NS name: ns8.nameservers.co.uk
M-PADD  -I- [drszalayeva.hu] NS addr: 146.247.49.116
M-ROK   -I- [drszalayeva.hu] SOA parameters comply with RIPE 
M-NS    -I- [drszalayeva.hu] A records for DNS servers:
    addr of NS ns2.nethely.hu.: 185.80.50.179
    addr of NS ns1.nethely.hu.: 185.80.48.121
M-PARI  -W- [drszalayeva.hu] NS records inconsistent with parent !!!
M-CSOA  -I- [drszalayeva.hu] checking SOA (2023021311) at 185.80.48.121
M-SOAN  -E- [drszalayeva.hu] No authoritative SOA at 185.80.48.121 over UDP
```

If I can fix this from my side: how? If not, whom should I contact next?

**EDIT:**
I wrote to Nethely, and they replied:

> Dear User!
> I don't understand the exact problem, what kind of problem occurred in the management of the domain.
> Based on domain.hu, I can see that the domain was not registered with us, and we do not manage its DNS zone. We cannot undertake the DNS service (name servers, DNS management) of domains not registered with us, so the ns1 and ns2 records pointing to us externally will be incorrect, we do not have a zone created for this type of domain management.
> If you want to add a domain name not registered with us to the hosting, you can of course do so. The following Knowledge Base article can also help with this: https://www.nethely.hu/tudasbazis/idegen-domain-csatolasa#-
> ​We cannot maintain the DNS zone of a domain name not registered/managed by us.
> If there is anything else we can help you with, please feel free to contact our customer service.

By visiting the **Knowledge Base** page I see that I have to ask the registrar to set the domain's DNS to the followings:

```
@   TXT     nethely-dvc=F0C0C[...etc...]

@   A   185.80.49.249
www     A   185.80.49.249
*   A   185.80.49.249
@   MX  mx1.nethely.hu. / priority: 10 /
@   MX  mx2.nethely.hu. / priority: 10 /
nethely._domainkey  TXT     v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANB[...etc...]
@   TXT     v=spf1 include:_spf.nethely.hu ?all
```

If drszalayeva.hu can get the very first hosting (which was the Cyber), then that would also be nice. Tomorrow, I'll call them again to know what they've prepared without these settings.

Comment: The problem is "NS parameter not given, getting it from DNS". You are doing an undelegated check, that is, no matter what tool you use you NEED to specify the nameservers to contact to check how the zone is installed on it. This is a test I just did using your new nameservers (`ns1.nethely.hu` and `ns2`): https://dnsviz.net/d/drszalayeva.hu/e/1570879/dnssec/ and it shows they are NOT configured correctly, at all. In all cases both your current registrar and DNS provider should be able to help you on this.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek are you saying that: The registrar should be able to set the NS values as asked, and the error should disappear afterwards?

Comment: Your domain registrar is probably not cyber.hu - they are not listed in the list of registrars for .hu - see https://www.domain.hu/regisztratorok/   - According to https://info.domain.hu/webwhois/en/domain/drszalayeva.hu your domain registrar is 23VNET Kft. (Registrar) - so you may want to reach out to them.   (It is possible that cyber.hu is a reseller of 23VNET - but its worth pointing out they are not very credible - their website does not support https, and looks like and has a copyright indicating it has not been changed significantly since 2007.)

Comment: Your registrar and DNS provider appear to be different.  It appears from the Google Translate of that Nethely  Knowledge Base article that you either need to use DNS services provided by your registrar (23VNET) or shift your domain registration to Nethely as they do not support offering DNS services for domains not registered through them...

Comment: Another possibility would be for you to go back to nameservers.co.uk, and add the zone file (ie the bit "set the domains DNS to the following" in your post above) to their records.   Note that you will need to update the nameservers so they are ns2238.nameservers.co.uk and ns8.nameservers.co.uk and keep an account with them.

Comment: I think that best solution would be to transfer the domain to Nethely, because the previous webserver (Netcetera), despite being free, the free webspace & service has limitations in how many times can we visit the website. The website was out of order, and people couldn't visit the site anymore. The problem is that we don't want to spend on this site, because the owner doesn't want to.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues here -

**First issue:**

According to the registar for .hu, your nameservers are still set as ns8.nameservers.co.uk ns2238.nameservers.co.uk.   These records need to be set at the REGISTRAR, not only in the DNS.  This is reflected in the authorative DNS as well:

```
dig @a.hu drszalayeva.hu ns

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> @a.hu drszalayeva.hu ns
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19257
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 3ba368d3841c9cac0100000063eb043d36174815d8705e27 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;drszalayeva.hu.            IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
drszalayeva.hu.     86400   IN  NS  ns8.nameservers.co.uk.
drszalayeva.hu.     86400   IN  NS  ns2238.nameservers.co.uk.

;; Query time: 312 msec
;; SERVER: 5.28.0.97#53(a.hu) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 14 16:47:09 NZDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

**Second Issue:**

nsX.nameservers.co.uk have got the nameservers nsX.nethely.hu set.   There are very few cases where this setting would be considered correct (its not correct here)  If First Issue 1 above was correct this would be irrelevant as no one would be looking to nsX.nameservers.co.uk to resolve drszalayeva.hu

```
dig @ns8.nameservers.co.uk drszalayeva.hu ns

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> @ns8.nameservers.co.uk drszalayeva.hu ns
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 142
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 2800
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;drszalayeva.hu.            IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
drszalayeva.hu.     86400   IN  NS  ns1.nethely.hu.
drszalayeva.hu.     86400   IN  NS  ns2.nethely.hu.

;; Query time: 292 msec
;; SERVER: 146.247.49.116#53(ns8.nameservers.co.uk) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 14 16:48:53 NZDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 87
```

**Third Issue:**

This is the largest issue - If you fix this, DNS will still be broken, but its likely the website will sort-of work - at least until nameservers.co.uk remove your zone from their nameservers **

The DNS (ie zone file) is not - or not correctly - configured on nsX.nethely.hu. You need to fix the DNS setup at nsX.nethely.hu.

When I query ns1.nethely.hu for drszalayeva.hu I don't get any meaningful answers - no SOA record, no NS records. This means that as far as the world is concerned, nsX.nethely.hu is not working properly with respect of your domain name and needs to be fixed.

```
dig @ns1.nethely.hu drszalayeva.hu soa

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> @ns1.nethely.hu drszalayeva.hu soa
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 3004
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;drszalayeva.hu.            IN  SOA

;; Query time: 308 msec
;; SERVER: 185.80.48.121#53(ns1.nethely.hu) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 14 16:49:27 NZDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

and

```
dig @ns1.nethely.hu drszalayeva.hu soa

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> @ns1.nethely.hu drszalayeva.hu soa
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 3004
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;drszalayeva.hu.            IN  SOA

;; Query time: 308 msec
;; SERVER: 185.80.48.121#53(ns1.nethely.hu) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 14 16:49:27 NZDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

Comment: Also "Can I set NS values on the webserver instead of on the nameserver?" - NO.  A webserver has no concept of DNS or NS values and does not normally talk on port 53 [port 53 being the port associated with DNS]

Comment: My question was sort of a poetical one. I was bounced back from the registrar, that first I have to set the "server" (not being specific here) and then will she be willing to set the NS values. It's just nonsense, like in the Banana Joe movie with Bud Spencer.

Comment: I don't know about .hu in particular, but in general it is a best practice to set up the nameservers (ie ns1.nethely.hu and ns2.nethely.hu) before updating the information at the registrar, but it should not be contingent on it.

Comment: So, I received an answer by phone, from Cyber, that .hu domains have to have the "settings" in the destination of the webspace. These domains are like that. Now I'm still stuck with this. I'm updating the question in a few minutes for a broader view.

Comment: @orghu  No offense, but I think you need to learn the relationship between Registrars, DNS and web hosting.    It is possible/probable that you need to map a virtualhost to a domain name in your web hosting, but this won't make any difference until you have your DNS sorted.     I do wonder if you understood "Cyber" correctly - as the advice in your updated post does accord with the answer you advise you received through phone....

Comment: If someone from Cyber did indeed advise you on the phone ".hu domains have to have the "settings" in the destination of the webspace", and they were asserting .hu domains are handled differently to other domains with respect of how DNS and WEB work, I am highly skeptical.    The bottom line is you need to  (a) Fix your DNS at nethely.hu then (b) Update the nameservers at your registrar and then (c) tackle any web hosting issues once DNS is sorted out.

Comment: I do have to correct myself, she didn't say that literally, I just fabricated that from my first quoting: "Please set the domain name on the new server. We cannot change the name servers until the domain name is set on the new server." This was somehow repeated in our latest conversation (that it differs from a .com domain).